# Using Conditional Compilation symbol in Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-services, class-library

I have used a class library which is being called by Web Application and Windows service. All of them are contained in a single solution.

I want to execute some code in the class library based on the call of application (**Web Application/Windows service**). I came across Compilation symbols and tried to implement it but that didn't work.

Please find below code:

```
#if WEB
        //call from web 
        //perform operation related to web
#endif
#if WindowsService
        //call from WindowsService
        //perform operation related to WindowsService
#endif
```

I have set the Compilation symbol **"WEB"** and **"WindowsService"** in my Web project and Windows Service project respectively by going to **Build** tab of Project properties.

Note: If I set the Compilation symbol in my class library project, then it works. But it doesn't satisfy my requirement.

Any help or new suggestion would be helpful!!

Comment: It shouldn't work because of different reasons and one of them that you want to change runtime behaviour using compile time tools.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan can you please give me another suggestions?

Comment: What is the problem, that the library can't be used on both configurations? If only a small part, that is used, either by one of them. You should splitup the assembly in total 3 assemblies. (the main library.dll / libraryWeb.dll / libraryService.dll)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a new solution configuration

Build\Configuration manager

Name the configurations as "web", "windows service"

Change the active configuration to "web"/"windows service", and for each project define the correct symbols (project properties\build\conditional compilation symbols"), save your projects and solution.

From now when you change your configuration the symbols will be correct.